# createAsyncThunk not dispatching "fulfilled" in test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I'm having some trouble testing some code which relies on an async thunk.

Here's my thunk:

```
export const signup = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/signup",
  async (payload, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://localhost:5000/auth/signup",
        payload
      );

      const cookies = new Cookies();
      cookies.set("token", response.data.token);
      cookies.set("email", payload.email);

      // TODO: parse JWT fields and set them as cookies

      // TODO: return JWT fields here
      return { token: response.data.token, email: payload.email };
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(
        actions.alertCreated({
          header: "Uh oh!",
          body: err.response.data.error,
          severity: "danger",
        })
      );

      throw new Error(err.response.data.error);
    }
  }
);
```

Here's the test that's calling it:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import { signup } from "store/auth-slice";

import { SignUpFormComponent } from "./index";

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const initialState = {
  auth: {
    token: null,
    email: null,

    status: "idle",
  },
};

jest.mock("axios", () => {
  return {
    post: (url, payload) => {
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: {
          token:
            "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MjA3MDcwODUwMDk3NDMwMDAsInN1YiI6ImZvb0BleGFtcGxlLmNvbSJ9.iykj3pxsOcFstkS6NCjvjLBtl_hvjT8X9LMZGGsdC28",
        },
      });
    },
  };
});

describe("SignUpFormComponent", () => {
  it("sends a signup request when the sign up button is clicked", () => {
    const store = mockStore(initialState);
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SignUpFormComponent />
      </Provider>
    );

    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText("Email address");
    userEvent.type(emailInput, "test@example.com");

    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText("Password");
    userEvent.type(passwordInput, "password");

    screen.debug();

    const submitButton = screen.queryByText("Submit");

    fireEvent.click(submitButton);

    const actions = store.getActions();
    console.log(actions);
    console.log(store.getState());
  });
});
```

In my output I see the following:

```
    console.log
      [
        {
          type: 'auth/signup/pending',
          payload: undefined,
          meta: {
            arg: [Object],
            requestId: 'LFcG3HN8lL2aIf_4RMsq9',
            requestStatus: 'pending'
          }
        }
      ]

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/signup-form/index.test.js:77:13)

    console.log
      { auth: { token: null, email: null, status: 'idle' } }

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/signup-form/index.test.js:78:13)
```

However, if I attempt to run through the flow myself through the browser it works fine, so I know that at least in the browser, the thunk's `FULFILLED` action is getting dispatched.

The component is dispatching the thunk like this:

```
  const [registration, setRegistration] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(signup(registration));
  };
```

If I debug the tests and set a breakpoint in the thunk, I can actually see the payload through and walk through all the way to the return, so that seems to indicate it's working.

At this point I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I would expect to see the fulfilled action in the mock store's `getActions` and I would expect to see the pending action called with a payload.

Answer (score 0):

`createAsyncThunk` always works asynchronously, while your test is synchronous. The `fulfilled` action will be dispatched a tick or two later, but at that point your test has already ended.

Make it async and wait for a moment.

```js
describe("SignUpFormComponent", () => {
  it("sends a signup request when the sign up button is clicked", async () => {

// ...

    fireEvent.click(submitButton);

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5))

    const actions = store.getActions();
    console.log(actions);
    console.log(store.getState());
  });
});
```

I'm sure there are better ways of doing it than that, but this should show you the basic concept.

Comment: Ah of course. Thank you for the answer. Even though it doesn't have an exact solution you've pointed me in the right direction. If I come up with a solution before someone else does I'll post it as an answer.